# skeletonization OpenCV In C#

Tags: c#, opencv

anyone could give me an example of how to skeletonization without using the transform of the distance, or if you have a skeletonization with the transform of distance running. I have an example with OpenCV in C #, more does not work.
cvlib.CvDistTransform (pimg ref, ref timg, (int) cvlib.CV_DIST_L2, 3, null, null);

An error in the parameters of the null, and I can not solve. if anyone knows how to solve, or some other example please show me.
I am working with OpenCV in C #, but if the example is with OpenCV in C + + or other liguam serves.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is another method explained here: http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-morphological-skeleton/

Below is the sample result :

[image]  [image]

It is very simple, and all functions are standard functions in opencv. It is Python, but will be easy to convert to C#.

Comment: This method might be useful for cuteness, but does not provide much analytical value, since it does not preserve topology in more complex shapes. (See this image of a mouse retina: https://i.imgur.com/NsVakyM.png -- the outlined contours should be about the same.)