# Canny edge Vs Skeletonization

Tags: opencv, image-processing, edge-detection, mathematical-morphology

I've been using Canny edge algorithm in my project up till now because there have been a lot of tutorials and examples on it. however for my case it seems skeletonization is yielding better results.

The first image : orginal, second image : canny, third image : skeletonization

[image]

I want to use skeletonization but i've been avoiding because in the back of my mind i keep thinking it must have drawbacks that i do not know of since no one seems to prefer this.

I want to know the advantages and disadvantages of each in general ?

Answer (score 1):

You should read the following links:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_skeleton

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector

More info:

[Need only one edge in Canny edge algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492533/need-only-one-edge-in-canny-edge-algorithm)

[skeletonization OpenCV In C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658325/skeletonization-opencv-in-c-sharp)